# Laravel Issue with variable scope in the query value gets lost. Ultra short code snippet

Tags: php, sql

Hello and good day to everyone

The issue is tricky (for me). I passed the parameter value from the controller to the model, and the model should use this value (held in a variable) but it loses it. I can echo that it does have it in the query but it loses as it progresses. I have pinpointed the issue to the most specific, so, if the answer is known, it is easy to fix it.

The value at $dato right at the last line shows variable undefined whereas lines above, $dato echoes the right value:

```
<?php
class Treatment extends Eloquent {


    public function sendData($dato){
         echo "en el model dato es: $dato";    <==  IT HAS IT OK HERE 
     $resultado = DB::table('treatments')      <==  IT LOSES ITS VALUE HERE
    ->whereIn('departamento', function($query)
    {
        $query->select(DB::raw('spec_description'))
              ->from('specialties')
              ->whereRaw('id_specialty', '=', $dato); <= SO IT DOES NOT GET IT HERE
    })
    ->get();

        return $resultado;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer, Try this,

```
<?php
class Treatment extends Eloquent {


    public function sendData($dato){
         echo "en el model dato es: $dato";    
     $resultado = DB::table('treatments')
    ->whereIn('departamento', function($query) use($dato)
    {
        $query->select(DB::raw('spec_description'))
              ->from('specialties')
              ->whereRaw('id_specialty = ?',array( $dato));
    })
    ->get();
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

I hope this should work...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested,  try this,

```
<?php
class Treatment extends Eloquent {


    public function sendData($dato){
         echo "en el model dato es: $dato";    //  IT HAS IT OK HERE 
     $resultado = DB::table('treatments')
    ->whereIn('departamento', function($query)
    {
        global $dato;
        $query->select(DB::raw('spec_description'))
              ->from('specialties')
              ->whereRaw('id_specialty', '=', $dato); // IT LOSES IT HERE
    })
    ->get();

        return $resultado;

    }


}
```

Comment: Is $dato a string?,   Try it,  whereRaw('id_specialty = ?', array( $dato ))

Comment: What you get global $dato; var_dump($dato); here is it shows NULL?

Comment: that means , $dato is available in whereRaw(), what about this,      ->whereRaw('id_specialty ='. $dato);

Comment: again the same result, undefined variable ..I actually included the var_dump above the start of the query, and if I included it inside, it simply shows nothing, as if I had not written it.

Comment: yes, part of the solution was exactly that: use($dato) because the closures have each their scope, but there was an additional issue, the final syntax. which is this one: ->whereRaw('id_specialty = ?',array( $dato));